# Pls make this accordion work for Dynamic Data

Tags: jquery, css

Iam having JQuery code below for menus accordion.. Actually this code works perfectly for Static dats, BUT unable to generate output properly in case of Dynamic data.. In my case, my code generated ul ,li, anchor tags generates automatically, so output not getting properly..

So, can anyone tell me how to make it work for Dynamic data too..?

Here is the code:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="robots" content="all" />
<title>jQuery Vertical Accordion Menu Plugin v 2.6</title>
<link href="css/dcaccordion.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.cookie.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.hoverIntent.minified.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/jquery.dcjqaccordion.2.7.min.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function($){


                        $('.accordion-6').dcAccordion({
                        eventType: 'hover',
                        autoClose: true,
                        saveState: true,
                        disableLink: true,
                        menuClose: false,
                        speed: 'medium',
                        showCount: true,

                        autoExpand: true,
                        cookie  : 'dcjq-accordion-1',
                        classExpand  : 'dcjq-current-parent',

                        menuClose: false    
                    });

});
</script>
<link href="css/skins/blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/skins/graphite.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="css/skins/grey.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrap">
    <div class="graphite demo-container">

            <ul class="accordion accordion-6">
                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Products</a>
                    <ul class="accordion"  id="accordion-6">
                        <li><a href="#">Mobile Phones &#038; Accessories</a> </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Desktop</a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a>
                <ul class="accordion"  id="accordion-6">
                    <li><a href="#">About Page 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Page 2</a></li>            
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
            </ul>

    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

BTW, from here I got this code:

```
http://www.designchemical.com/lab/jquery-vertical-accordion-menu-plugin/download/
```

Hope someone would provide solution for my prob..

Thanks!

Comment: Hard to give an _exact_ answer, but you need to load the dynamic data, and _then_ wire up the accordion.

Comment: HOwz that possible? If you dont mind, could you pls tell bit brief on your idea.. any examples..?

Comment: Post the code you use to add the dynamic data/html to the dom.

Comment: I also just noticed you're using `accordion-6` as the `id` on multiple elements.  An `id` needs to be unique.

Comment: Hey, now my prob got resolved as i just changed in my dynamic code and its working fine now.. BTW, Iam using space between 2 classes, so whats wrong in that..?

Comment: You can set classes like that.  `class="first-class second-class third-class"`.

Comment: Yes Gromer, even I did the same thing, Right..? Even I have kepted space between each class.. Am I wrong..?